# Почему SimpleDateFormat.parse() выбрасывает java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-02-14T00:02:18.000Z"

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Имеем код:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String strDT = "2017-02-14T00:02:18.000Z";
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    Date date = format.parse(strDT);
    System.out.println(String.format("%1$tD %1$tT", date));
}
```

Имеем вот такой выход:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-02-14T00:02:18.000Z"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
at main.Main.main(Main.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Вопрос: ПОЧЕМУ?

Answer (score 6):

Причина в "Z".

Старый вариант парсинга дат (`java.util.Date`) не умеет работать с этим символом, поэтому в ваше случае нужно сделать так:

```
    String strDT = "2017-02-14T00:02:18.000Z".replaceAll("Z$", "+0000")
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    Date date = format.parse(strDT);
    System.out.println(String.format("%1$tD %1$tT", date));
```

Либо можно использовать Java 8 (пакет `java.time`):

```
    String strDT = "2017-02-14T00:02:18.000Z";
    Instant i = Instant.parse(strDT);
    System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

Собственно я заменил в формате Z на 'Z'.
Но ответ @Evgeny Lazarev мне в принципе понравился.